# Ubuntu 19.04 - I accidentally removed gnome icon themes

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, gtk

I recently accidentally removed all the icon themes and couldn't recover them from my trash. Is there any way I can re-install these themes?

**These are the specs from screenfetch**

OS: Ubuntu 19.04

Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-73-generic

DE: GNOME

WM: GNOME Shell

GTK Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3]

Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-light
Font: Ubuntu  Light 11

*I only deleted the icons.*
*Oops I made a typo. I meant 18.0**4***
*Oops I made a worse typo. I meant 1**9**.04*

Thanks for the solution guiverc, but one thing occurred to me after I rebooted my laptop. *The icons were different from the regular ubuntu 18.04 icons.*
*because i apparently had 19.04*

See Screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your release; there was no Ubuntu release in 2018-May (18.05)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197808/gnome-accidentally-removed-default-icon-themes

Comment: @guiverc The solution you provided gives me different icons.

Comment: Found out why. I wasn't actually running 18.04, but rather 19.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-desktop

shows

> ```
> gnome-accessibility-themes
>     High Contrast GTK+ 2 theme and icons
> ```

so `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-accessibility-themes`

Ubuntu-mono themes are located in `ubuntu-mono` package  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-mono) 
so `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-mono` will re-install those.